# Relation of gravitational pull with no air friction

Tags: newtonian-gravity, mass, acceleration

I am confused between the gravitational pull and the air friction on the moon.
Let me give you an example,

I have learned that the greater the mass of the body the more gravitational force it generates.

The other point is,
On the moon, there is no  air friction so if we drop a feather and a hammer, both will reach the surface simultaneously.

My question is,
The mass of the Hammer is clearly more than that of feather.
Shouldn't it be pulled toward Moon faster than the feather due to greater gravitational pull?

How come, the gravitational pull be constant from the moon for all the object regardless of their mass?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why objects of different masses accelerate at the same speed under gravity](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90694/)

Comment: [Related question.](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11321/)